# how to pass a jquery function as a parameters of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

```
function secondFunctionName(){
  return value;
}

function functionName( parameter){
   // do something with the parameter
}

<input onclick="functionName(secondFunctionName)" />
```

1. My question is how to pass secondFunctionName() as a parameter of functionName()
2. what if function secondFunctionName() has parameters e.g. function secondFunctionName(data), how to do that?

Comment: Just as an aside - once you start messing around with functions as parameters, you might want to start looking into closures too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using straight JavaScript quite easily -

```
var secondFunctionName = function(){
  return value;
}

function functionName( parameter){
    // do something with the parameter
    var myValue = parameter();
}

<input onclick="functionName(secondFunctionName)" />
```

You will have to invoke that function in your functionName, however.

Answer (score 0):

if your going to use returned value of a function into another function same as an argument
I think there is just one way to do that and I hope it help's you

```
function functionOne(){
   return value;
}
var result = functionOne();
function functionTwo(result){
   // do something with the parameter
}
```

or i think this one shoud work too

```
function functionOne(){
   return value;
}
function functionTwo(functionOne()){
   // do something with the parameter
}
```

Comment: Regarding the second - that will work, but it really doesn't pass the function as a parameter.  All you are doing is evaluating that function call and using the result.